# Java agent OTel not working with New Relic

Tags: java, javaagents, open-telemetry

I have a Java application running with an OTel agent to collect telemetries and send them to the New Relic platform.

Configuration of OTel Java agent:

```
-javaagent:./agents/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar
-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp
-Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name=my-application
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.headers=api-key=${NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY}
```

When this app is starting an error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot find a NameResolver for https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Which version of the OTEL javaagent are you running? Are you able to resolve `otlp.nr-data.net` e.g. `nslookup otlp.nr-data.net` on the system where this Java app is running?

Comment: @JanGaraj the OTel javaagent version is 1.12.1, locally this application works fine, but when deploying the app on the server this error occurs, I tested `ping` and `telnet` at host `otlp.nr-data.net` are responding correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved for me when adjusting `Dockerfile` forcing the download of OTel java agent on the image build process.

From:

```
COPY ./agents/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar .
```

To:

```
ADD https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/download/v1.12.1/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar .
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=otlp.nr-data.net:4317
```

[OTLP endpoint should be officially URL](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/protocol/exporter.md#configuration-options) (so scheme part should be included), but some implementations need it without scheme part. I guess this is your case.

Comment: This format is invalid, it causes this exception `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: otlp.nr-data.net`.